# Using a final variable in java and its implications on methods

Tags: java, final

Im modifying a large class file. The easiest way to achieve what I want is to change the class' global variables to 'final' and set the value. But I havent used finals much. Will this cause a problem with the setter methods throughout the file? i.e. what happens when a setter cannot set the variable as the variable is final? An error? Or just ignored? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Horseshaq. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please formulate a better question by reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why is making everything final your best solution? It * may* screw everything up-especially setters, obviously. Sounds like an XY problem so far.

Comment: I am modding a Jenkins plugin for my company and many of the options this plugin gives they dont want. While I could go through and remove all references to them its just easier to set the variables to the default they want. I just wasnt sure how java handles setter methods that cant set a variable. From the answer below it seems I must remove the setters also as it will cause an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fields  are `final`, they must be set either on declaration or in the constructor. Once set, the compiler will throw an error when set again, because final variables are not allowed to be re-assigned.

Comment: Thanks. Its the error part I needed to know. I will remove all setters too so there are no errors

Comment: If my answer helped you, don't forget to accept it :)